# Haskell / repa - is there a way to pretty-print matrices?

Tags: haskell, matrix, repa

Using repa in haskell, is there a way to print matrices so they're nicely formatted with matrix rows being on separate lines (the default for most numerical computing environments like R or matlab)?

I could write one, but it seems like something that would already exist.

This type of output is unwieldy to interact with:

```
λ> foo
AUnboxed ((Z :. 3) :. 5) (fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Maybe it's worth adding to repa or a repa-extras package?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module PrettyPrint where

import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Matrix

import Text.PrettyPrint
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJClass

instance (Source t a, Pretty a) => Pretty (Array t DIM1 a) where
 pPrint a = brackets $ hcat $ punctuate (comma <> space) elems
    where
     elems = [ pPrint (a!j) | i <- [0..n-1], let j = Z :. i ]
     Z :. n = extent a

instance (Source t a, Pretty a) => Pretty (Array t DIM2 a) where
 pPrint a = vcat elems
   where
     elems = [ pPrint (slice a j) | i <- [0..n-1], let j = Any :. i :. All]
     Z :. n :. _m = extent a
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this seems pretty basic. I don't know how others get by without such a basic thing. Maybe some people are using repa in batch mode and not interactively.

Comment: btw, do you mostly use hmatrix over repa these days? does the maturity of hmatrix still trump the advantages of repa?

Comment: Depends on the application. If you want to solve something like a diffusion then repa is probably appropriate. If you want to do standard linear algebra then hmatrix is probably better. Also hmatrix has a nice static module. It would be nice to put something like this on top of repa also.